# How to get the length of an array from a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm having trouble finding the length of an pointer array. Let's say I have:

```
char array[40] = "hello"; // size 40
int length =  sizeof array / sizeof array[0]; // no problem returns 40
```

//How do I get the length of the array with only a pointer to the first element in that array?

```
 char* pchar = array;
```

//if

```
std::strlen(pchar); // this returns the length of 5... i want length 40
```

//if

```
int count = 0;
while(true)
{
  if(*(pchar + count) == '\0') // returns 5...
    break;
   count++;
}
```

How do I get it to return length 40 just from a pointer to the first element in the array?
I found that I can do this.

```
int count = 0;
    while(true)
    {
      if(*(pchar + count) == '\0' && *(pchar + count + 1) != '\0') 
             break;

       count++;
    }
```

This returns 39, this is good but I feel like this can be buggy in some situations.

Comment: You can't get the length of an array from a pointer.

Comment: There are hacks, but there is no builtin way to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't, I'm afraid.  You need to pass the length of the array to anyone who needs it.  Or you can use a `std::array` or `std::vector` or similar, which keep track of the length themselves.

Comment: hmm but my last block of code returned 39, +1 = 40. why is this bad?

Comment: @JavaNewb: You're reading off the end of the array into undefined memory, which is likely to cause a crash.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. And the moral is, don't use pointers and arrays, use vectors. You can always get the size of a vector.

Answer (score 5):

C++ has proper string type:

`std::string`

which you may find helpful here. Even if you're passing it to function that accepts `const char*`, it has `.c_str()` method that allows you to pass it to function that accept a pointer. If the other function needs to modify the string, you can use `&str[0]` which is valid for many implementations of C++, and is required to work for C++11. Just make sure you resize() them to the correct size.

Some of the other containers in C++ are:

`std::array` (C++11) Array of constant size. Better than plain old C array, as it has `size()` method.
`std::vector` Dynamic array (Java `ArrayList` equivalent)

As for your question - there is no way to find size of a pointed array. How could you even do that? It's just a stupid pointer.

Comment: **Even if you're passing it to function that accepts char*, it has .c_str() method that allows you to pass it to function that accept a pointer.**  
  
==> That is incorrect.  The `c_str()` member function returns a `const char *`.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps You're right. That was my oversight here.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that you cannot get the array size from a pointer to an element of the array.

If the reason you only have a pointer is because you are implementing a function that takes an array parameter as an argument like this:

```
void foo (T *p) {
    // p is a pointer to T
}
```

then you can use a template function instead to get the array size to the function.

```
template <unsigned N, typename T>
void foo (T (&p)[N]) {
    // p is a reference to an array[N] of T
    std::cout << "array has " << N << " elements" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "array has "
              << sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0])
              << " elements"
              << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    int array[40];
    char array2[25];
    foo(array);
    foo(array2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, yes, so the full answer would be: you can't get the array size from the pointer to an array but if it's an option instead of passing pointer to an array to a function you could pass reference to an array and then you can get the size using code from this answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep simple and not use `#include <array.h>`, you can make a struct where you array sizes are. A little bit like:

```
struct
{
    int* int_Array;
    int array_Size;
}
```

That way, you can to whatever you want (like deleting your instances or something)